# What is the proper way to free memory from an ldap_parse_reference call?

Tags: c, openldap

The documentation for ldap_parse_reference says to free the references with a call to ldap_value_free (see **http://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_parse_reference** for the man page.)  However, the routine ldap_value_free is deprecated.

Any pointers to the proper way to do it?  (Note that I looked at the openldap code and saw that some of the code was using ber_memvfree, but that didn't seem right to me.  I didn't like the mixing of the calls and the docs didn't say to do it that way.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went and looked at the openLDAP code.  In the file clients/tools/ldapsearch.c, the routine print_reference does a call to ldap_parse_reference.  The resulting references are freed (after printing) by a call to ber_memvfree((void **)refs).

I can only presume that this is the correct way to free the memory.

Answer (score 0):

`ldap_value_free()`, as the man page you cited says. Where in the [man page for `ldap_value_free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_value_free) does it say it's deprecated?

Comment: It's deprecated in the source (see: http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;a=blob;f=include/ldap.h;h=673dcc3e5d823603701d6fc806a5cd7bac9ba035;hb=HEAD#l1835). It references the `ldap_value_free_len()` function as an alternative.

Comment: @Ben It's certainly not deprecated in its own manual page, or the one for `ldap_parse_reference() either.

Comment: Ben's link clearly shows that the prototype is only available when LDAP_DEPRECATED is defined and nonzero.

Comment: @Ben - the man page for ldap_value_free_len has as its parameter a struct berval **.  However, I only have a char **.  It doesn't seem to fit the situation.